# https redirect with Apache is returning a blank page

Tags: apache, redirect, https

I have a WAMP installation running on a Raspberry pi 3. Apache v2.4.33, php 7.2.4.

I want the default url address of my site - "//www.quintic.co.uk/" - to actually address "//www.quintic.co.uk/index.php?home". So I added the following to the .htaccess file:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php?home
```

I have also configured Apache to always use https protocol, by updating the apache config file with the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [END,NE,R=permanent]
```

For the most part, all the above seems to be working perfectly. For example, if I request http://www.quintic.co.uk/ then I am redirected to https://www.quintic.co.uk/index.php?home.

All http requests are switched correctly to https requests.
All https requests are returning correctly, with the exception of https://www.quintic.co.uk/, which returns a blank page.

The actual instruction set returned from a https://www.quintic.co.uk/ request is as follows:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-eqiv="refresh" content="0" url="https://www.quintic.co.uk/index.php?home" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ff.kis.v2.scr.kaspersky-labs.com/E989763D-7B5C-014A-B514-22905C3EEE53/main.js" charset="UTF-8"></script></head>
<body>
</body>
<!-- End of #container-->
<!--Scripts after page loads-->
</html>
```

If I cut & paste the url in the meta statement into a browser, the home page is returned fine.

Can anyone shed some light on why the default url redirect is not working with https.

Thanks

SteveD430

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the apache2.conf. Within the Quintic site 'Directory' element. I had the following:

```
AllowOverride None
Order allow,deny
allow from all
Require all granted
```

It needed to be 
`AllowOverride All`

Site is now working perfectly.